# pyodbc error when connecting to SQL database "Cannot open database "database3" requested by the login."

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I have a database that I connect to that has previously worked and come back to the script a few months later and now its stopped working and im getting the error below :

> conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + DB['servername']
>   + ';DATABASE=' + DB['database'] + ';Trusted_Connection=yes' + ';UID=' + DB['user'] + ';PWD=' + DB['password'])
>
> ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database "database3" requested by the
>   login. The login failed. (4060) (SQLDriverConnect); [42000]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database
>   "database3" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060)')

I can connect using the same credentials using SQL server server management studio version 18 and query the database in question.   I'm using the following version numbers:

```
Python: 3.6.7 
Pandas: 1.0.3
pyODBC: 4.0.27 also tried upgrading this to 4.0.30.
```

The code im using to connect is :

```
# parameters for connecting to SQL databse 
DB = {'servername': 'server\sqlexpress',
      'database': 'database3',
     'user':'sa',
     'password' : 'Password'}

# create the connection
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + DB['servername'] + ';DATABASE=' + DB['database'] + ';Trusted_Connection=yes' + ';UID=' + DB['user'] + ';PWD=' + DB['password'])
```

Can some help me solve this problem?

Comment: You should be providing `UID=...;PWD=...` **OR** `Trusted_Connection=yes`, not both. If you want to use SQL Authentication (as opposed to Windows Authentication) then use `Trusted_Connection=no` (or just omit it altogether).

Comment: thanks that solved my problem.  not sure how that mistake creaped into my jupyter notebook.  Did you want to write it as a answer?  so i can assign you as giving the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be providing `UID=...;PWD=...` **OR** `Trusted_Connection=yes`, not both. If you want to use SQL Authentication (as opposed to Windows Authentication) then use `Trusted_Connection=no` (or just omit it altogether).